# Selection Sort Summation Simplification

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, summation

I am trying to simplify the summation for selection sort. Starting out with:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}1$$

I am able to get:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}n-i-1$$

However, I don't understand how to simplify this summation any further. I don't know if I should pull the n outside of the summation, and I don't know what to do about the $i$. I would appreciate any help and detailed steps in how one gets from one step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write your expression as 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left( n-i-1\right)$$ to make clear that you are summing not just $n$ but also the $-i-1$ terms.

The $n$ inside the term being summed ummation sign is just a constant during the summation. The $i$ in the expression being summed is the summation index in the outer sum. So you get
$$n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left( 1 \right) -\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(  i\right) - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left( 1 \right) = n^2 - \frac{(n-1)n}{2}- n = \frac{n^2-n}{2}$$

Comment: Ok. That is what I did, but I was using the following link: http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~algorith/video-lectures/2007/lecture3.pdf and the answer given on slide 12 is $(n-1)(n-2)/2$ so I was wondering if I'd made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

"Pulling outside" is generally done when you have the product of $2$ terms, such as

$$\sum_{k=0}^nak=a\sum_{k=0}^nk$$

When summing terms, however, you can split the summation into parts.  For this example

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(n-i-1)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(n-1-i)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(n-1)-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i$$

Now, for that first sum, since nothing inside the summation depends on $i$, it's just a simple multiplication.  The second summation is an arithmetic sequence that you're hopefully familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Another way
is to reverse the order of summation.

In
$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(n-i-1)$,
let $j = n-1-i$,
so $i = n-1-j$.

At $i=0$, $j=n-1$;
at $i=n-1$, $j = 0$.

Therefore
$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(n-i-1)
=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(n-(n-1-j)-1)
=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(j)
=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}
$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=i}^{N}1=\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{i=1}^j1=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\binom j1=\binom {N+1}2=\frac {(N+1)N}2$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}1&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=i}^{n-1}1\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i}^{n-1}1\\
&=\binom n2=\frac{n(n-1)}2\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$